# Why do I keep getting 'Nan' values when I try to add a column from a csv dataframe to an existing dataframe both opened on pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing dataframe (df1) in the format below:

```
Date        Adj Close   Return
2019-01-02  475.365143  NaN
2019-01-03  468.232574  -0.015004
2019-01-04  480.232086  0.025627
2019-01-07  479.644653  -0.001223
2019-01-08  491.644226  0.025018
```

and a separate csv file (df2):

```
    Date        Daily SONIA Rate
0   2019-01-02  0.7044
1   2019-01-03  0.7048
2   2019-01-04  0.7046
3   2019-01-07  0.7052
4   2019-01-08  0.7052
```

I am trying to add another column to the first dataframe (df1) that subtracts the daily SONIA rate (df2) from the Return in df1 and returns a column in df1 with the results. Every possible means I have tried just returns the following:

```
Date        Adj Close   Return      Exreturn    
2019-01-02  475.365143  NaN         NaN
2019-01-03  468.232574  -0.015004   NaN
2019-01-04  480.232086  0.025627    NaN
2019-01-07  479.644653  -0.001223   NaN
2019-01-08  491.644226  0.025018    NaN
```

Would really appreciate some help.

Tks!

Comment: What's the output when you run df1.dtypes? What does your code look like for adding another column?

Comment: Hi Blake, my last line of code that resulted in the Nan values is:

df1.assign(Exreturn=df1['Return']-df2['Daily SONIA Rate'])

Tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your indexes are different. `df1` seems to have `Date` as its index but `df2` has `Date` as a column.

Set `df2`'s index to `Date` and you should be able to create the column as expected:

```py
df2 = df2.set_index('Date')

df1['Exreturn'] = df1['Return'] - df2['Daily SONIA Rate']

#       Date   Adj Close    Return  Exreturn
# 2019-01-02  475.365143       NaN       NaN
# 2019-01-03  468.232574 -0.015004 -0.719804
# 2019-01-04  480.232086  0.025627 -0.678973
# 2019-01-07  479.644653 -0.001223 -0.706423
# 2019-01-08  491.644226  0.025018 -0.680182
```

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank you sooooooooooooo much! Really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
df1['Exreturn'] = df1['Return'] - df1.Date.map(df2.set_index('Date')['Daily SONIA Rate'])
```